# Event Analytics App just shows blank dashboard

Tags: analytics

I created one Event Analytics App, with following settings:

> Enable Event Log File Integration with Event Monitoring Analytics App: Enabled
>
> Enable Login Forensics: Enabled

I ran the dataflow created by the App. On running the dataflow I get following error:

> The dataflow was completed, but the LookupSingleValue node didn't
> augment any columns. Either the node didn't find any matches, or a
> join key contains only null values.

Then I see all the dashboards are blank for the app.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I created a ticket with Salesforce, not much help though.

Comment: I'm guessing there's an error with the data.  Check your Data Manager>Monitor>Dataflow View for details.  I'm dealing with this same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this issue and solved it by waiting until the next day.  Apparently the data wasn't present in the Wave/Einstein platform for the LookupSingleValue node to match against.

Comment: you are right. It starts working with time. I just scheduled the run every morning, and the app runs fine now.

Comment: I've set the job to run hourly, but still don't see the data. And see the warning for AugmentAPIUser. I don't see any rows ExtractAPIFile as well. Should I wait even the schedule is set for 1 hr? I'm able to fetch the EventLog file through Workbench though.